# Weird IE7 div resize float bug? Form buttons remain fixed!

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer-7

I have a form:

```
<form>
<div id=content> form content (fields, etc) </div>
<div id=buttons> 
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>submit button</td>
      <td>cancel button</td>
    </tr>
  </table> 
</div>
</form>
```

When I display error messages, the content div gets a bit bigger in height to fit in the error messages.

The weird thing is, in IE7 ONLY, the buttons div gets pushed down as it should, but the buttons remain fixed, thus the top content div is overlapping the buttons by a bit!! HOWEVER, if I move my mouse over the buttons (I assume it's triggering a hover?), they move themselves down.

wtf?

Comment: Impossible to know what's going on without seeing your CSS as well.

Comment: need css. there could be floated elements, there could be relative positioning, the secret ghost of ie could be moving your elements around. we can't tell much without the full picture. the best answer you'll get as of right now is a good guess, which may or may not work.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using [this](http://ajaxian.com/archives/forcing-a-ui-redraw-from-javascript) to see if a forced redraw will correct things.